# how to update the login role password using SQL query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

In my [postgresql-9.2](/questions/tagged/postgresql-9.2) I've created 3 *roles* called `root`,`sale`,`purchase`.
At this moment all the 3 *roles* have same password, so how can I *update* password of each *roles* using *query*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [**ALTER ROLE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-alterrole.html)

```
 ALTER ROLE root WITH PASSWORD 'your_password';
```